# faster alternative to windows.h's Beep()

Tags: c++, windows, beep

I'm working on a personal project. I want to transmit some data over the air with an old ham radio.

My first draft application works like that :

I construct one byte with 4 "signals" :

- 5000hz means "00"
- 6khz means "01"
- 7khz means "10"
- 8khz means "11"
- 9khz means same as the previous one

then I merge those 4 couple of bits together and start again with the next one.

The demodulation works great and should be fast enough, but I'm having an issue with the sound generation... it's slow...

Here's my debug code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Beep( 5000, 100 );
Beep( 6000, 100 );
Beep( 7000, 100 );
Beep( 8000, 100 );
Beep( 9000, 100 );
return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting 5 beeps, close together, 100ms each but here's what I get (on top, five "100ms Beeps(), and on the bottom, five "20ms Beeps()"  :
[image: a]

As you can see, what I get is 50ms beeps followed 75ms pause when I want 100ms beeps, and 10ms beeps followed by 100ms pause when I want a 20ms beep.

**Is there something faster and more accurate than Beep() for Windows ? (something that works with linux as well would be even better because the final application should work on a raspberry pi)**

I would get the higher usable bandwidth with 3ms sounds (.... 41 bytes/sec.... which is more than enough for my application)

Compiler : g++ (mingw)

Os : seven 64bits

Comment: `Beep()` is definitely the wrong tool for this job. It's not designed to be precise by any means. You would need to generate the waveform data and write them to a sound card (or equivalent), which is inherently platform-specific. Another option is using a microcontroller that modulates the signal and attach it to your computer (which would make porting the code somewhat easier).

Comment: You are going to need to pick a single operating system. The solution you go for on Windows is unlikely to be the same on the pi.

Comment: @In silico, using a microcontroler is going to be a last ressort solution (I'm fairly confortable with atmel's µCs and have the necessary tools to etch my own pcbs but I'd rather go without the extra hardware)

Comment: Please also be sure to 1) have a valid amateur radio license before transmitting on any of those frequencies; and 2) Select a frequency that allows experimental communication modes. The FCC has *no* sense of humor when it comes to people transmitting without a license, or using the wrong mode for a band.

Comment: @Xearinox: And if he's from some country other than USA, then his country's laws regarding amateur radio are as strong or stronger and he stands to get into even more trouble than what a US resident would get into from the FCC.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: OK I delete my comment, but consider valid frequencies in some countries are different then as USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (which would be suitable since you want to target Linux too) would be to generate a WAV file, then play that. (There are simple ways to [play](http://www.mplayer2.org/downloads/) WAV files on both Windows and Linux.)

You could use a library to generate the WAV file, or create it yourself, both approaches are pretty simple. There are many [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29676/CWave-A-Simple-C-Class-to-Manipulate-WAV-Files) on the web.

If you do it yourself:

```
/* WAV header, 44 bytes */
struct wav_header {
    uint32_t riff packed;
    uint32_t len packed;
    uint32_t wave packed;
    uint32_t fmt packed;
    uint32_t flen packed;
    uint16_t one packed;
    uint16_t chan packed;
    uint32_t hz packed;
    uint32_t bpsec packed;
    uint16_t bpsmp packed;
    uint16_t bitpsmp packed;
    uint32_t dat packed;
    uint32_t dlen packed;
};
```

Initialize with:

```
void wav_header(wav_header *p, uint32_t dlen)
{
    memcpy(p->riff, "RIFF", 4);
    p->len = dlen + 44;
    memcpy(p->wave, "WAVE", 4);
    memcpy(p->fmt, "fmt ", 4);
    p->flen = 0x10;
    p->one = 1;
    p->chan = 1;
    p->hz = 22050;
    p->bpsec = hz;
    p->bpsmp = 1;
    p->bitpsmp = 8;
    memcpy(p->dat, "data", 4);
    p->dlen = dlen;
}
```

Comment: I tried that first (with a perl script tough) but it had the same kind of pauses between sounds and somekind of lag before the sound actually started (very short (few ms) sounds never started...). I'm gonna look for a c++ solution to do this, thanks.

Comment: @srsbsns, can you generate a bunch of pulses in advance? Then there should be no pauses. If you try to generete only 5 WAV files and play them, then you need low latency playback and mixing APIs. I.e. I suggest not to play a bunch of WAV files, but to generate one WAV file with your whole message.

Comment: @srsbsns, I'd mention, be aware of endian issues when writing header, but Raspi and x86 are both little endian, so no convertion should be necessary.