# Simple sounds in C++

Tags: c++, audio

Using C++ 11 in Visual Studio 2012, I'm trying to sounds which I've observed in Pascal.  In Pascal, it seems like you're able to send a frequency to the internal speaker, which plays this frequency until you tell it to stop (or until you tell it to play a different frequency).  So here's what I need:

- I must be able to specify the frequency of the sound
- The sound must have little or no gap (up to maybe 5ms would be acceptable)
- I do not want to use external sound libraries (please do not waste my time by suggesting them, unless they are **incredibly** lightweight and provide an exceptionally wide range of use)
- Preferably, the sound would be played on internal speaker, rather than through the computer's regular speakers

I can't find any include-able libraries/headers in visual studio which provide the ability to send a waveform to the internal speaker.  I'm willing to try to work directly with the internal speaker (I know this would be hard, but I'm not an idiot - I think I can figure it out, with some guidance), but I can't find any documentation on accessing the internal speaker in Windows.

**EDIT**: From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216931/play-sound-on-internal-speakers-and-possibility-to-use-old-xp-api-function), I was able to gather that most computers nowadays don't actually have an internal speaker.  Bummer.  That's fine though - I can use the connected speakers, but I still have the following requirements:

- I need to be able to specify a frequency and have the speakers play that frequency until I tell them to stop
- I would rather not use external libraries

**EDIT 2**: Here's the class I'm working on:

```
#define HALF_NOTE 1.059463094359 // HALF_NOTE ^ 12 = 2

#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>

class SoundEffect
{
public:
    SoundEffect(){}

    void Play()
    {
        for (int i = 0; data[i + 1] > 0; i++)
        {
            Beep(16 * pow(HALF_NOTE, data[i++] - 1), data[i] * 10); // (frequency of c0) * (twelfth root of 2) ^ (number of half steps above c0)

            // Ideally, the code would look more like this (pseudocode):
            // sound(16 * pow(HALF_NOTE, data[i++] - 1)); // Start playing the specified frequency
            // delay(data[i] * 10);
        }
        // nosound();
    }

    int& operator[] (int location) { return data[location]; }

private:
    int data[256];
};
```

Comment: Something like [Beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Back in the day, those sounds were not played "directly on the sound card", but from the internal speaker. PCs mostly did not have sound cards until Pascal was not used any more.

Comment: Machines don't have speakers anymore.  Guess why Beep() still works :)

Comment: Beep() won't work, because the gap between tones is much too long (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992253/faster-alternative-to-windows-hs-beep)).  I suppose I could try some really hacky solution using Beep() and threads to eliminate the gap, but aside from how ridiculously convoluted this would be, I'm not sure this would work, and I don't want to waste a lot of time on something that might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Windows Multimedia API to create waveforms and send them to the sound device.  I based my solution off of a tutorial [here](http://www.tmsoft.com/tutorial-sound.html).  Here's what I ended up with:

```
#define HALF_NOTE 1.059463094359 // HALF_NOTE ^ 12 = 2
#define PI 3.14159265358979

#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class SoundEffect
{
public:
    SoundEffect()
    {
        m_data = NULL;
    }
    SoundEffect(const int noteInfo[], const int arraySize)
    {
        // Initialize the sound format we will request from sound card
        m_waveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;     // Uncompressed sound format
        m_waveFormat.nChannels = 1;                    // 1 = Mono, 2 = Stereo
        m_waveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 8;               // Bits per sample per channel
        m_waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 11025;           // Sample Per Second
        m_waveFormat.nBlockAlign = m_waveFormat.nChannels * m_waveFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8;
        m_waveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = m_waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * m_waveFormat.nBlockAlign;
        m_waveFormat.cbSize = 0;

        int dataLength = 0, moment = (m_waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec / 75);
        double period = 2.0 * PI / (double) m_waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec;

        // Calculate how long we need the sound buffer to be
        for (int i = 1; i < arraySize; i += 2)
            dataLength += (noteInfo[i] != 0) ? noteInfo[i] * moment : moment;

        // Allocate the array
        m_data = new char[m_bufferSize = dataLength];

        int placeInData = 0;

        // Make the sound buffer
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i += 2)
        {
            int relativePlaceInData = placeInData;

            while ((relativePlaceInData - placeInData) < ((noteInfo[i + 1] != 0) ? noteInfo[i + 1] * moment : moment))
            {
                // Generate the sound wave (as a sinusoid)
                // - x will have a range of -1 to +1
                double x = sin((relativePlaceInData - placeInData) * 55 * pow(HALF_NOTE, noteInfo[i]) * period);

                // Scale x to a range of 0-255 (signed char) for 8 bit sound reproduction
                m_data[relativePlaceInData] = (char) (127 * x + 128);

                relativePlaceInData++;
            }

            placeInData = relativePlaceInData;
        }
    }
    SoundEffect(SoundEffect& otherInstance)
    {
        m_bufferSize = otherInstance.m_bufferSize;
        m_waveFormat = otherInstance.m_waveFormat;

        if (m_bufferSize > 0)
        {
            m_data = new char[m_bufferSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < otherInstance.m_bufferSize; i++)
                m_data[i] = otherInstance.m_data[i];
        }
    }
    ~SoundEffect()
    {
        if (m_bufferSize > 0)
            delete [] m_data;
    }

    SoundEffect& operator=(SoundEffect& otherInstance)
    {
        if (m_bufferSize > 0)
            delete [] m_data;

        m_bufferSize = otherInstance.m_bufferSize;
        m_waveFormat = otherInstance.m_waveFormat;

        if (m_bufferSize > 0)
        {
            m_data = new char[m_bufferSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < otherInstance.m_bufferSize; i++)
                m_data[i] = otherInstance.m_data[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    void Play()
    {
        // Create our "Sound is Done" event
        m_done = CreateEvent (0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

        // Open the audio device
        if (waveOutOpen(&m_waveOut, 0, &m_waveFormat, (DWORD) m_done, 0, CALLBACK_EVENT) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) 
        {
            cout << "Sound card cannot be opened." << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Create the wave header for our sound buffer
        m_waveHeader.lpData = m_data;
        m_waveHeader.dwBufferLength = m_bufferSize;
        m_waveHeader.dwFlags = 0;
        m_waveHeader.dwLoops = 0;

        // Prepare the header for playback on sound card
        if (waveOutPrepareHeader(m_waveOut, &m_waveHeader, sizeof(m_waveHeader)) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        {
            cout << "Error preparing Header!" << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Play the sound!
        ResetEvent(m_done); // Reset our Event so it is non-signaled, it will be signaled again with buffer finished

        if (waveOutWrite(m_waveOut, &m_waveHeader, sizeof(m_waveHeader)) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        {
            cout << "Error writing to sound card!" << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Wait until sound finishes playing
        if (WaitForSingleObject(m_done, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            cout << "Error waiting for sound to finish" << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Unprepare our wav header
        if (waveOutUnprepareHeader(m_waveOut, &m_waveHeader,sizeof(m_waveHeader)) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        {
            cout << "Error unpreparing header!" << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Close the wav device
        if (waveOutClose(m_waveOut) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        {
            cout << "Sound card cannot be closed!" << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Release our event handle
        CloseHandle(m_done);
    }

private:
    HWAVEOUT m_waveOut; // Handle to sound card output
    WAVEFORMATEX m_waveFormat; // The sound format
    WAVEHDR m_waveHeader; // WAVE header for our sound data
    HANDLE m_done; // Event Handle that tells us the sound has finished being played.
                   // This is a very efficient way to put the program to sleep
                   // while the sound card is processing the sound buffer

    char* m_data; // Sound data buffer
    int m_bufferSize; // Size of sound data buffer
};
```

Pretty complicated, but it works.  I use it with text files like this (the sound effects for DOS mario & luigi):

```
LifeMusic 56 8 61 8 65 8 61 8 63 8 68 8
GrowMusic 37 4 44 4 49 4 38 4 45 4 50 4 39 4 46 4 51 4
CoinMusic 66 1
PipeMusic 13 0 13 8 1 0 1 16 13 0 13 8 1 0 1 16 13 0 13 8 1 0 1 16
FireMusic 41 1 46 1
HitMusic 25 2 13 3 1 4 25 1 13 2 1 3
DeadMusic 25 3 13 4 1 6
NoteMusic 1 3 13 4 1 6
StarMusic 37 4 41 4 44 4 49 4 53 4 56 4 61 4 65 4 68 4 73 4
```

To give a brief overview, my main file reads in these lines.  For each line, it creates a sound effect from an array of the integers, and creates a map where the keys are the names of the sound effects, and the values are the created `SoundEffect` instances.

In the text file, each line should have an even number of integers.  If you break a single line of integers into pairs, the first number will be the number of half steps above A1 (in order to determine the frequency), and the second number will be the duration, in 75ths of a second (arbitrary, I know).

Comment: I think you should include a <Windows> tag in your question, since the chosen solution is OS specific. I look for something like this to work on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I search for something like that (generating simple sounds) a little while ago and found these libraries that would do the job:

- [PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/)
- [Nsound](http://nsound.sf.net/)
- [The Synthesis ToolKit (STK)](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/)

I haven't had the time to try and compare them, though. Have fun with that :)